# Image Slider Using View Pager(With Transparent Toolbar)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have Created an Image Slider using View Pager by following some tutorials.
So my problems is I wanted my slider to have a transparent toolbar.
And when i clicked on the screen the toolbar will hide.
Here's my code together with the output(I made), and the output i Want.

1. My Activity

   ```
   public class viewInfo extends AppCompatActivity{
   private ViewPager viewPager;
   private Toolbar toolbar;
   private CustomSwipeAdapter adapter;
   PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_info);
       toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
       adapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
       viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


   }


   public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
       private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.bsu, R.drawable.gameover2};
       private Context context;
       private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

       public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context context) {
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return image_resources.length;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
           return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
       }

       @Override
       public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
           layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, (ViewGroup) container, false);
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
           imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
           imageView.setImageResource(image_resources[position]);
           ((ViewGroup) container).addView(item_view);

           mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
           mAttacher.update();
           return item_view;
       }

       @Override
       public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
           container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

2.XML(swipe_layout)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

3.XML(My Activity's XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.thesis.juandirection.juandirectionfinale.viewInfos.viewInfo">


    <include
        android:id="@id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

What i want Is this effect..
Transparent toolbar.
I tried to put a listener to Linearlayout that when the user
clicked the layout it will hide the toolbar, but no luck.
[image]
[image: When i touch the screen, actionbar(transparent) will hide]

Comment: Maybe its easier to make a custom view that performs similar to the standard toolbar?

Comment: customview? how to do that?

Comment: ohh. i get it.. but my problem is i can't trigger any action event.

Comment: help pls.. i really need your help guys

Comment: Create your own view instead of using toolbar, that way you can do anything you need.